# reorganise a data structure

Tags: dataset, matrix

I need to restructure my data, at the moment it looks like:

Question number (39 total) in the header
**Participant ID** |  **Response** ( x 39 columns referring to Q numbers in the header) | **Demographic** x 5 questions/columns |

and i need it to look like:
no question numbers in header
**Participant ID** |  **Question number** (39 rows, 1 column)| **Response** (1 column) | **Stimulus Type** (I will add this information separately) | **Participant Correct** (I will add this information separately) **Demographic** * 5 questions/columns |

I have a blank matrix to fill but I'm nervous about moving information and losing the structure of what entries correspond to each other, especially as I need to move the data in square/rectangular chunks rather than by column or by row. Some data such as participant ID and demographic information needs to be duplicated as each participant gets multiple entries in the second layout. For the question and and response part cutting and pasting might be best so that I can see what is done and not done.

Does anyone have a good method for restructuring in this way?